# leading-order behaviour of riemann zeta function?

Tags: asymptotics, riemann-zeta-function

Is there any 'guess' as to how the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(\sigma+it)$ (or its modulus) behaves to leading order as $t\rightarrow\infty$, for fixed $\sigma$ in the critical strip? Obviously this can't be known for sure until at least the Lindelof Hypothesis is solved, but have people come up with *either* a good guess based on numerical data *or* a definite answer with the assumption of the Riemann Hypothesis?

I know the Lindelof Hypothesis (which is a consequence of RH) would give $\zeta(\sigma+it)=O(t^{0.5-\sigma+\epsilon})$ for $\sigma\le0.5$ and $\zeta(\sigma+it)=O(t^{\epsilon})$ for $\sigma\ge0.5$, but I'm looking for something like $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|\sim Kt^{0.5-\sigma+\epsilon}$ or $K(\log t)^{\alpha}t^{0.5-\sigma+\epsilon}$ for some constants $K$ and $\alpha$.

Many thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Here is the good document related to your question http://home.olemiss.edu/~mbmilino/MicahThesis.pdf

Comment: I am not getting it? Is your "I'm looking for something...." not stronger then LH, which is certainly not known?

Comment: @plusepsilon.de: Yes, it is stronger than LH. I know no such result has been *proved*; I was just looking for either numerical data or consequence of RH (which implies LH).

Comment: $\zeta$ gets arbitrary small in $1/2 \leq \Re s <1$. I am not sure about $0< \Re s <1/2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An asymptotic result is *much* stronger than a Big Oh bound, and no results like the ones you hope for can be true:  In Titchmarsh's "Theory of the Riemann Zeta Function", Theorem 11.9 shows that for fixed $\sigma_0$ in the interval $(1/2,1]$, the values of $\log(\zeta(\sigma_0+it))$, $t>0$ are dense in the complex plane.  In particular, the real part $\ln|\zeta(\sigma_0+i t)|$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Update in response to comment below:  The theorem in Titchmarsh referenced above was generalized by Voronin:  Let $D_r$ be the closed disk of radius $r<1/4$ centered at $3/4$, and let $f$ be *any* function holomorphic on the interior of $D_r$, and continuous and non-vanishing on $D_r$.  For any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $t$ such that
$$
\max_{s\in D_r}\left|\zeta(s+it)-f(s)\right|<\epsilon.
$$

This is Voronin's "Universality Theorem."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality  refers to this as
"the remarkable ability of the Riemann zeta-function to approximate arbitrary non-vanishing holomorphic functions arbitrarily well."

Another point of view for the behavior of $\zeta(s)$ on lines in the critical strip is given by the Theorem of Bohr and Jessen:  There is a continuous function $F(z,\sigma)$ such that for any rectangle $R$ with sides parallel to the real and imaginary axes, as $T\to\infty$,
$$
\frac{1}{2T}m\{t\in [-T,T]:\log(\zeta(\sigma+it)\in R\}\to\iint_RF(x+iy,\sigma)\, dxdy.
$$
Here $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

The Riemann zeta function is too complicated an object for its absolute value to have an asymptotic on lines in the critical strip.

Comment: OK, so that means we can't get leading-order asymptotics for $\zeta$ itself. But what about $|\zeta|$? Even if the values it takes are dense in $\mathbb{R}^+$, something like $|\zeta(\sigma_0+it)|\sim\log(t)$ would be possible without violating this.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. So the only value of $\sigma$ where there might possibly be a result like what I'm looking for is $\sigma=0.5$, and even that's unlikely!

Comment: Not at $\sigma=0.5$, either.  See this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268268/argument-of-the-riemann-zeta-function/268324#268324